# Extract warnings from BIM 360 hosted revit models using forge API

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk, autodesk-bim360

Is there an exposed Autodesk's Forge API endpoint that can give warnings associated with the Revit model hosted in BIM 360?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Webhooks](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/webhooks/v1/developers_guide/basics/) to generate warnings for [events](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/webhooks/v1/reference/events/) related to BIM 360 files or folders.

Also, please check [forge-checkmodels-createissues-revit](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-checkmodels-createissues-revit), as it covers a useful workflow integrating BIM 360, Webhooks, and Desing Automation.

Comment: Thanks, João Martins. let me try the mentioned reference you have stated.